# Problema al visualizar datos en un campo select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En la vista edit.blade no logro que se visualicen los datos disponibles de un campo select, me aparece repetido el dato seleccionado previamente en la vista create y no me aparecen los otros datos.
Aqui dejo captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo el codigo de la vista Create del campo Tipo de Incidencia:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
                <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Mensual">Ing. Receta Mensual</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Seguimiento">Ing. Seguimiento</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Seguimiento">Ing. Co-Pago</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Y aqui el campo Tipo de Incidencia de la vista Edit que es donde sucede el incidente:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
                <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
                      <option value="{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}" selected>{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}</option>
                      <option value="{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}">{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Buen día, veo que en las líneas

```
<option value="{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}" selected>{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}</option>
<option value="{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}">{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}</option>
```

Están duplicando las opciones del campo select.

Para que puedas llenar correctamente ese componente deberías tener un array que iterar para llenar las opciones algo como esto:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
           <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
               @foreach($pmincidenciaArray as $pmincidencia)
                   <option value="{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}">{{$pmincidencia->Tipo_incidencia}}</option>
               @endForeach
           </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

Saludos